# Polybius square puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Find the coordinates get out of that square then take one step back and see the answer

> 24-34-45-24-21-24-12-34-15-44-35-22-45-24-21-14-35-15-21-23-24-52-21-43

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 6):

Begin with the ciphertext:
24-34-45-24-21-24-12-34-15-44-35-22-45-24-21-14-35-15-21-23-24-52-21-43

Find the coordinates
get out of that square

> Decode using a standard Polybius square to get plaintext:
>  iouifiboetpguifdpefhiwfs
>  The standard polybius square does not distinguish between letters i and j, so the following is also valid plaintext given the ciphertext:
>  jouifiboetpguifdpefhjwfs

then take one step back and see the answer

> Take our second decoded plaintext and use the caesar cipher to rotate all letters back by 1:
>  inthehandsofthecodegiver